# How to make a toggle function in .vimrc that toggles multiple configs of almost same type?

Tags: vimscript, key-bindings, neovim

My .vimrc code

```
autocmd FileType cpp nnoremap <F4> :RunWithFile 
autocmd FileType cpp nnoremap <F4> :RunWithFile ~/Downloads/ > output.txt && cat output.txt<s-left><s-left><s-left><s-left><s-left><left>
```

When i need to use any of the two, i have to uncomment/comment out every time. 
opening my vimrc file and editing it.. such a drag 
finally i intend to do something about it.

Can anyone help me make **a config in vimrc which toggles these** (almost same) **commands?**

PS: i searched about this everywhere. yet couldn't find a way how to do that. 
I did find a thread [Toggle function in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20579142/toggle-function-in-vim) in stackoverflow but solution is to make a plugin (which i don't want)

therefore, it's not a keymap which i can just `unmap` and it's done.
You can see from my vimrc, those two are same mapping but slightly different (additional commands)

Comment: What criteria determine whether to use one config or the other? And are you looking to swap between the two while working on an individual file or just have the swap take place the next time the autocommand is triggered?

Comment: @BLayer i want to swap between the two while working on an individual file

Comment: @BLayer your code was good.. only problem is that only after typing `\X` i could access to `<F4>` .. `:RunWithFile` was not by default .. but toggle was great :)

Comment: how can i fix it? You deleted your answer right after you gave me a hint

Comment: forgot to tell you.. maxim-kim's code doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, Maxim Kim's solution was close to perfect, the only missing thing is that the exact command to run should be specific to the current project. IOW, the value to use should be buffer local.

As this is something I do a lot in my plugins, I've factorized everything regarding [option fetching](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/doc/Options.md) to option toggling (I also have a `:Toggle` command).

Anyway. A poor man's solution could be the following.

```
" ~/ftplugin/cpp/cpp_yourmappings.vim
" When I have several ft-specific things to define I avoid polluting the .vimrc

" Little helper that simplifies my lh#option#get() command
" See https://old.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/p5zgdp/can_someone_explain_variables_to_me/h9cx7f5/
let s:GET_OR = { key, default -> filter([w:, b:, t:, g:, {key : default}], {_,v -> has_key(v, key)})[0][key]}

let s:k_option_name = 'run_cpp_with_options'

" yap + p from Maxim Kim's solution
function! s:RunCpp() abort
    let with_options = s:GET_OR(s:k_option_name, 0)
    if with_options
        let cmd = ":RunWithFile ~/Downloads/ > output.txt && cat output.txt\<s-left>\<s-left>\<s-left>\<s-left>\<s-left>\<left>"
    else
        let cmd = ":RunWithFile"
    endif

    call feedkeys(cmd)
endfunction

function! s:toggle(scope) abort
    let dict = a:scope == 'b' ? (b:) : (g:)
    let dict[s:k_option_name] = ! s:GET_OR(s:k_option_name, 0)
    echo printf('%s:%s <- %s', a:scope, s:k_option_name, dict[s:k_option_name])
    " I haven't tried to handle cases like b:foo and g:foo exist and we want to toggle g:foo
endfunction

" To execute
nnoremap <buffer> <silent> <F4> :<c-u>call <sid>RunCpp()<cr>
" To toggle locally
nnoremap <buffer> <silent> <F5> :<c-u>call <sid>toggle('b')<cr>
" To toggle globally, without resetting any previously existing b:values
nnoremap <buffer> <silent> <F6> :<c-u>call <sid>toggle('g')<cr>
```

Note: I haven't tested the code. If the `feedkeys()` part doesn't work, I'll revert to old solutions that always work: a simple `return cmd` + `<c-r>=` should do. (I've learned to avoid `feedkeys()` but I've trusted previous answer)

Comment: it doesn't work in my neovim v0.5.0 .. Could you please rewrite blayer's code as i mentioned?

Comment: Could you paste me the error message?

Comment: i removed `<silent>` from the mapping and used.. but still it shows no error.. does nothing

Comment: I've just tested it with nvim 0.4.4 where it works fine. Do you at least have the (new!, see the edit) log on `<F5>`? If not may be it's because I've replaced clumsy autocommands with a filetype plugin that needs to be dropped in the right configuration directory (that I don't know precisely w/ nvim). ftplugins have to be enabled, and the file needs to be put into the right place.

Comment: Tested with Linux v0.5.0 appimage as well.

Comment: would you please look at b-layer's code https://pastebin.com/raw/ZQ0kNKR0 .. And I'm having this [problem](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/34393/how-to-make-a-toggle-function-in-vimrc-that-toggles-multiple-configs-of-almost/34398?noredirect=1#comment61917_34393) .. by the way, i prefer this code ..with this, i can toggle multiple configs .. maybe you can help fix that :)

Comment: can you make a default variable (global) in b-layer's code? i'm not being able to do this. vim throws an error.. the `rwfcmd1` isn't an expression or variable something like that

Comment: I've voluntarily avoided toggling between several mappings -- as it has a few side effects. The simple solution is the one chosen by Maxim: a single mapping that never changes, and that executes a string built depending on the configuration (a variable). If you want more complex solutions, may be it's not toggling that you're looking for but local vimrcs.

Comment: Regarding variables, you've said: _"i want to swap between the two while working on an individual file"_ that's definitively an hint that the setting shall not be global but local.
If you really want a global setting and never switch from one buffer to the next, just replace the `s:GET_OR`  with `get(g:, varname, 0)` and force the use of `g:`  in toggle.

Comment: Also, I was thinking we cannot use a global variable to update buffer-local mappings. The value of the variable and the mappings will quickly go out of sync as changing the global variable shall trigger the change in all related buffers. I've done it, this is a headache to write and to maintain. Somehow this is the same neophyte/beginner's error as analysing the filetype of the current buffer in the `.vimrc`. TL;DR: Definitively a single and unique mapping and variables (global or not) to tune the exact mapping is the way to go. This is what is simpler and what is working correctly.

Comment: How can i have more commands like this in a single `feedkeys()` ?

Comment: In normal scenarios, we just execute the command, directly. May be through a `:execute` if there are some dynamic parameters. `feedkeys()`  essentially serves to end-up in interactive mode in order to permit to edit the exact parameters to `:RunWithFile` before executing it.