# Need help to make a by-default `:RunWithFile` of this toggle function

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, neovim

related to this post, [How to make a toggle function in .vimrc that toggles multiple configs of almost same type?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/34393/how-to-make-a-toggle-function-in-vimrc-that-toggles-multiple-configs-of-almost)

@BLayer's code

```
func! MapRunCmd() abort
    if exists("b:rwfcmd1") && b:rwfcmd1
        nnoremap <buffer> <F4> :RunWithFile ~/Downloads/ > output.txt && cat output.txt<s-left><s-left><s-left><s-left><s-left><left>
        let b:rwfcmd1 = 0
    else
        nnoremap <buffer> <F4> :RunWithFile
        let b:rwfcmd1 = 1
    endif
endfunc
nnoremap <leader>x :call MapRunCmd()<cr>
```

Gist of this post is: "toggling an almost same command while working on an individual or multiple files" 
this toggle function works as expected but it has **a little problem**.

##### Current situation:

here, `:RunWithFile` is not by default 
Only after typing `\x` i can access to `<F4>`

typing `\x` for the first time activates `:RunWithFile` .. then typing `\x` for the second time, it toggles.

##### Expected solution:

I want `:RunWithFile` to be default. so that typing `\x` one time, vim can toggle easily. 
`:RunWithFile` will be

```
:RunWithFile ~/Downloads/ > output.txt && cat output.txt
```

I won't have to type twice (activate `:RunWithFile` then toggle)

Hope you folks can help me fix this

PS: i tried to use `b:` `g:` equal to 1 outside this function 
but it didn't work. Don't know why

```
let b:rwfcmd1 = 1
let g:rwfcmd1 = 1
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129394/discussion-on-question-by-mega-bang-need-help-to-make-a-by-default-runwithfile).

Answer (score 0):

This is (roughly) how I would write this with your skeleton: we add an
autocommand to do the initial mapping on any buffer enter. If you want it for
particular files, change the autocommmand's pattern. If you want it for
particular filetypes, you're better off putting the `call MapRunCmd()` in
`~/.vim/after/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim`.

```
function! MapRunCmd() abort
  if exists("b:rwfcmd1") && b:rwfcmd1
    nnoremap <buffer> <F4> :RunWithFile ~/Downloads/ > output.txt && cat output.txt<s-left><s-left><s-left><s-left><s-left><left>
    let b:rwfcmd1 = 0
  else
    nnoremap <buffer> <F4> :RunWithFile
    let b:rwfcmd1 = 1
  endif
endfunc

augroup map_to_RunWithFile
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile * call MapRunCmd()
augroup END
nnoremap <leader>x :call MapRunCmd()<cr>
```

But consider if you can create a single global mapping like `nnoremap <leader>x :call RunWithFileArgs()<cr>` where `RunWithFileArgs` can use something like
`b:run_with_file_args` if it exists (or nothing):

```
function! RunWithFileArgs() abort
  const args = get(b:, 'run_with_file_args', '')
  call feedkeys(':RunWithFile '..args)
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>x :call RunWithFileArgs()<cr>
```

Then in your ftplugins or autocommands or what have you, just `let b:run_with_file_args = '…'`. For `<s-left>` you probably would have to use
`"\<s-left>"` with double quotes instead of single.

I take a similar approach with my [simpl
plugin](https://github.com/benknoble/vim-simpl) and its use of `b:interpreter`.